# XML wrapper JSON format issue

Tags: java, xml, json, xml-parsing

I have this class:

```
 class A {
      @XmlElement(name = "bees")
      @XmlElementWrapper(name="bee")
      public List<B> bees;
    }
```

And my XML then looks something like:

```
<a>
  <bees>
    <bee>...</bee>
    <bee>...</bee>
  </bees>
</a>
```

However when use through JSON:

```
{
  "bees": {
    "bee": [
      ....
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to be:

```
  {
  "bees": {
    "bee": { .. }, "bee": { .. }, ..
  }
}
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended with something like:

```
public class BeeDetails
{
    public string details { get; set; }

}

public class Bee
{
    public BeeDetails { get; set; }
}

public class BeeResponse
{
    public List<Bee> Bees { get; set; }
}
```

to get this:

```
 {
  "bees": {
    "bee": { .. }, "bee": { .. }, ..
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Instead of:

```
{
  "bees": {
    "bee": { .. }, 
    "bee": { .. }, 
    ..
  }
}
```

I would recommend the following:

```
{
   "bees" : [ 
       { .. }, 
       { .. },
       ..
   } ]
}
```

Below is how MOXy could be used to produce this JSON based on your mappings:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_WRAPPER_AS_ARRAY_NAME, true);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {A.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("src/forum19560166/input.xml");
        A a = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, A.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        marshaller.marshal(a, System.out);
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/binding-to-json-xml-handling-collections.html

Answer (score 1):

use this [tools](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/278-how-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java/);t I ran into the same issue you have described. The solution we used to get this to work was to change our Maven dependency from Jackson to json-lib. We used this site as a [guide](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/278-how-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java/):

add dependency to your pom if use maven.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xom</groupId>
        <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

save this xml in sample file sample-xml.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <important-data certified="true" processed="true">
      <timestamp>232423423423</timestamp>
      <authors>
        <author>
          <firstName>Tim</firstName>
          <lastName>Leary</lastName>
        </author>
      </authors>
      <title>Flashbacks</title>
      <shippingWeight>1.4 pounds</shippingWeight>
      <isbn>978-0874778700</isbn>
    </important-data>
```

Main class

```
package com.discursive.answers;

import java.io.InputStream;

import net.sf.json.JSON;
import net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class ConvertXMLtoJSON {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                InputStream is = 
                        ConvertXMLtoJSON.class.getResourceAsStream("sample-xml.xml");
                String xml = IOUtils.toString(is);

                XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer(); 
                JSON json = xmlSerializer.read( xml );  
                System.out.println( json.toString(2) );
        }
}
```

Result

```
{
  "@certified": "true",
  "@processed": "true",
  "timestamp": "232423423423",
  "authors": [  {
    "firstName": "Tim",
    "lastName": "Leary"
  }],
  "title": "Flashbacks",
  "shippingWeight": "1.4 pounds",
  "isbn": "978-0874778700"
}
```

Comment: java heap space error when using large xml file. thanks for the help though